# $_SERVER and $_ENV not available if running php from shell

Tags: environment-variables

I have set up a cron job to run once an hour a script `cron/cron.php`
This script simply reads a table to check which scripts should run at a given time.
So far no problem.
I just noticed that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is empty. Same to `$_ENV['HOSTNAME']`

What can be the reason? I would prefer to have my `cron.php` portable so I am searching for a solution which should work on every server.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

When the cron script is run, it's most likely executed by the php-cli binary and not the webserver.

`$_SERVER` entries are set by the webserver, here is the [quote from `$_SERVER` page in the PHP manual](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server):

> `$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server.

As there is no webserver involved with your cron script, these are not set. You can try this your own by executing php on the command-line:

```
php -r 'var_dump($_SERVER);'
```

it will output all settings in `$_SERVER` in your command-line environment, "`DOCUMENT_ROOT`" most likely will be an empty string and "`SERVER_NAME`" is not set at all.

The `$_ENV` superglobal contains the environment variables of the system specifically, it's just that "`HOSTNAME`" is not set as environment variable by the cron binary.

### Further Considerations

I normally suggest to not only create the PHP cron script (as you did with `cron/cron.php`) but also to create a shell-script that invokes the php script. Then use the shell-script in the crontab. This allows you to modify the environment easily without re-configuring the crontab or the `cron.php` too often. You can then set environment variables within that shell script as well as changing the working directory etc.

If you want to make your `cron.php` script more portable, figure out what the injected environment dependencies are (e.g. the document root your have) and make those variable, e.g. with variables or a parameter object. Then create a section in your script where those variables are populated and the rest of your script can run based on them in an injected manner. This reduces configuration changes only to a very limited part of your script and will allow you to create more re-useable code.